# Need to count the cells where time is later than a given value

Tags: time, sum, set

direct to the point
[heres the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OZimG.jpg)

i need to get only the time thats over 9am and sum them all up at cell E35
this may sound easy to you guys and tell me it is, but im sorry, i just cant, im still a noob at this.
please help, thank you.

Comment: You might want to tag the tool you're using... i.e. Google Sheets or Excel...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formula you need is `COUNTIF`. In your case, put the following formula in cell E35:

```
=COUNTIF(E4:E34, ">09:00")
```

### Updated

I think this is what you actually want:

```
=SUMIF(E4:E34, ">09:00") - COUNTIF(E4:E34, ">09:00") * TIMEVALUE("09:00")
```

This will add up all the times in the N cells that exceed 9:00 am and subtract N lots of 9 hours from the total.

Comment: i feel like its super close to this, but unfortunately, im only getting a result of "0:00" :(

Comment: That all depends on how you have formatted your cells. If they are formatted as 'TEXT' then it won't recognise that it is a time. You can use `TIMEVALUE` to convert it, or change the column type to `TIME'. I have created a sample spreadsheet that illustrates the difference for you to download: https://www.dropbox.com/s/125ukxm1tajh714/TimeCountSample.xlsx?dl=0. Good luck.

Comment: it is formatted as Time 13:30, and i think you dont get what i mean, i only need the values of the time that surpasses 9am, if its A1)9:02, A2)9:04, A3)8:57, E35 should just be 0:06, only counting :02 + :04

Comment: you got it! thanks very much, but almost got confused to how to understand it to be honest, since im new to this, you forgot to add bracket in the multiply stuff, good thing my brain still functions and remember MDAS so i figured it multiplied first the countif*timevalue then subtract whats left to the sumif. this formula stuff is so complex for my tiny human brain. thanks for the help! :D

Comment: No problem @JonathanF. I didn't put in brackets because of operator precedence. If Excel sees this formula it will do the * operator before the -, so you should be safe. However putting brackets does no harm if it helps you to understand what is going on